# Analogy between a Gödelian puzzle and Gödel's first incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, puzzle, incompleteness

I'm studying Gödel's incompleteness theorems. And I have the following [slide](http://prntscr.com/9lr8si) that defines a version of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem. The point is that one can always follow the math and get the feeling that he/she grasps the idea behind the math, but Gödel's incompleteness theorem seems a bit different. It is so deep and has many consequences.

There is also the [puzzle](http://prntscr.com/9lr9ot) (most probably by Raymond Smullyan), and I believe that I found one unprintable statement, which is ¬PN(PN(w)). Of course, I may be wrong, but it made sense to me.

Then, I read that there is an analogy between this Gödelian puzzle and the actual proof of the [Theorem GT](http://prntscr.com/9lr8si), that is provided in the slide in my link above (I also linked it here for convenience).

The point is that I don't exactly see this analogy. If someone can explain me this analogy I would be glad. Both mathematical and informal explanation is highly welcomed.

Comment: For a simple (but correct) exposition og G's Theorem, see [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I still have a hard time in figuring out the analogy with the puzzle that I have linked.

Comment: Well, if you want "informal" there's this.  A formal logic statement has statements that are either true or false and they are true if they are not false and false if they are not true.  A system can create the sentence "this sentence is false" which can neither be true nor false and the system breaks down.  The puzzle has some formal method of making a sentence that basically means "This sentence is not printable" Such a sentence would be true and not printable.  Godel's incomp th. give a formal language to construct statements "the statement is unverifyable in this language".  Similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The machine does not print any non-true sentence.

This is *correctness*. A formal system $F$ is *correct* (with respect to an interpretation) if it proves only true sentences, i.e. if $F \vdash A$, then $A$ is true.

> Can it print every true sentence ?

This is asking for *completeness*. A formal system $F$ is *incomplete* when there are sentences of the language of $F$ which can neither be proved nor disproved in $F$, i.e. there is a sentence $A$ such that neither $F \vdash A$ nor $F \vdash \lnot A$.

But one of $A$ and $\lnot A$ is true in the interpretation we are considering, and thus one of them is a true sentence that cannot be proved by $F$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but how exactly is this puzzle analogous to G's Theorem's proof?

Comment: @pandora - because in both cases the "trick" [much more complex for G's Th] is to build a £self-referential" formula; in the case of the puzzle, it must be a sentence that asserts its own non-printability, i.e. $\lnot PN( \lnot PN)$.